# Injectivity of the evaluation map from holomorphic functions to a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, holomorphic-functions

In Functional Analysis, we have covered Functional Calculus, that is, a way to associate, once having fixed a Banach algebra $A$ and an element $a\in A$, an element $\tilde f(a)\in A$ to every $f$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of the spectrum of $a$, via an integral formula, in such a way that $f\mapsto\tilde f(a)$ is an algebra homomorphism, $\tilde f(a)=e$ (the identity) if $f\equiv1$, $\tilde f(a)=a$ if $f(z)=z$, the subalgebra of $\tilde f(a)$'s is commutative even if $A$ is not, and these properties characterize this $f\mapsto \tilde f(a)$ map. On one occasion, the professor, being asked if this mapping was injective, replied:

> Uuuh, è iniettiva, certo, fino a quando, ovviamente, tengo fisso l'elemento, quando pói cambio l'elemento, chi lo sa.

i.e.:

> Uuuh, is it injective, of course, up till, of course, I keep the element fixed, when I change the element, who knows.

I smell rat here. After all, $\mathbb{C}$ is a B.A., and this mapping is certainly not injective, in general, since $f(z)=z$ is certainly not the only holomorphic map sending $z_0$ e.g. into itself, yet this mapping is clearly $f\mapsto f(z_0)$, in this case, if the fixed $a$ from above is $z_0$. So what did she mean? Are there conditions under which this is injective indeed? Perhaps as soon as the spectrum is not a single point for each element (i.e. as soon as we leave $\mathbb{C}$) this mapping becomes injective?

Comment: The domain of the map $f \mapsto \tilde{f}(a)$ is not $\mathbb{C}$, it's the algebra of functions that are holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $\sigma(a)$ (the spectrum of $a$). That is not a Banach algebra (it's not normable), but it's an inductive limit of Banach algebras (only 99.9% sure, though). The map is injective (by the identity theorem) if $\sigma(a)$ contains no isolated points.

Comment: @DanielFischer I meant to take $A=\mathbb{C}$ and construct that mapping there. Fix $a\in A$ or rather $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, we have $f\mapsto f(z_0)$, and that is not injective in general, e.g. for $z_0=1$ $f(z)=z^2$ and $f(z)=z$ coincide on 1, so $f\mapsto f(1)$ is not injective. I never said the mapping in question had $\mathbb{C}$ as its domain. But then this case is one where the spectrum has an isolated point, and thus the mapping _can_ be (and is indeed) not injective. Identity theorem, huh? Let me look for it in my book…

Comment: You mean [this one](http://planetmath.org/identitytheorem)? How does injectivity follow from that?

Comment: Ah, you meant $\mathbb{C}$ as the codomain. Yep, it's highly non-injective then. Whenever you have an isolated point in the spectrum, the map is non-injective, and two functions agreeing on the spectrum give the same element of $A$, and if you have an isolated point, two holomorphic functions agreeing at that point need not agree on a neighbourhood of that point.

Comment: @Daniel Precisely. Um, what relation is there between $\tilde f(a)=\tilde g(a)$ and $f=g$ on $\sigma(a)$? For the moment, all I know is that $\tilde f(a)$ is invertible iff $f\neq0$ on the whole spectrum, and that the spectrum of $\tilde f(a)$ is the image via $f$ of that of $a$ (Spectral Mapping Thm). Can I use this to conclude some relationship between the above? Something like one (or maybe even two) implications?

Comment: Yes, that one. Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $\sigma(a)$. If $\sigma(a)$ contains no isolated points, then if $f \in \mathscr{O}(U)$ vanishes on $\sigma(a)$, the identity theorem says $f\lvert_V \equiv 0$ for every component $V$ of $U$ with $V \cap \sigma(a) \neq \varnothing$. Then there is an open $\sigma(a) \subset W \subset U$ (the union of components intersecting the spectrum) with $f\lvert_W \equiv 0$. So the class of $f$ in the inductive limit is $0$. Then there's the slightly nontrivial part $\tilde{f}(a) = 0 \iff f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} \equiv 0$ left.

Comment: Which, on second thought, has a problem if the Banach subalgebra of $A$ generated by $a$ contains nilpotent elements. Or any elements $x\neq 0$ with $\sigma(x) = \{0\}$. So let's assume $\sigma(x) = \{0\} \iff x = 0$ for $x\in A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Classes? Inductive limit? Err… oh, [inductive limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit). But what inductive limit? You mean something like germs, that is, in Wikipedian notation, $I$ is the set of neighborhoods of $\sigma(a)$, $A_U$ is the (Banach) algebra of holomorphic functions on the neighborhood $U$ of the spectrum, and $\phi_{UV}$ is the restriction to the neighborhood $V$ of functions holomorphic on $U$?

Comment: Something along those lines, but the algebra of holomorphic functions on a nonempty open sets is not normable. For a bounded nonempty open $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, let $A(U) = \mathscr{C}(\overline{U}) \cap \mathscr{O}(U)$, and endow it with the maximum norm. That's a closed subalgebra of $\mathscr{C}(\overline{U})$, so a Banach algebra. For $W \subset U$, we have the natural restriction $\rho^U_W \colon A(U) \to A(W)$. Letting $U$ range over the (open) neighbourhoods of $\sigma(a)$, we get an inductive system, and we look at its inductive limit.

Comment: And I got things a bit backward at the end yesterday night. If $\sigma(a)$ has no isolated points, then $f\mapsto \tilde{f}(a)$ is injective is seen thus: By linearity, we need to see that $\tilde{f}(a) = 0 \implies f = 0$. By the spectral mapping theorem, $\{0\} = \sigma(\tilde{f}(a)) = f(\sigma(a))$, so $f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} \equiv 0$. Take a representative $f_1 \colon U_1 \to \mathbb{C}$ of $f$, and let $U_2$ be the union of components of $U_1$ intersecting $\sigma(a)$. Let $f_2 = f_1\lvert_{U_2}$. By the identity theorem $f_2 \equiv 0$, and hence $f = [f_1] = [f_2] = 0$.

Comment: The other direction, that $f\mapsto \tilde{f}(a)$ is not injective if $\sigma(a)$ has isolated points only holds if $\sigma(x) = \{0\} \implies x = 0$. Consider the Banach algebra $B = \bigl \{ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} z & w \\ 0 & z\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) : z,w\in \mathbb{C}\bigr\}$, and $a = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. Let $f(z) = z^2$, then $\tilde{f}(a) = a^2 = 0$, but $f\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: I can't quite see why that counterexample works @Daniel. After all, $\{0\}$ has (only) an isolated point (0) and the mapping $f\mapsto\tilde f(a)$ is not injective with $a$ being that matrix which has an isolated point in the spectrum, since the spectrum is just zero. So it's a perfect example of isolated points giving a non-injective map. A counterexample would have to be an element of a B.A. whose spectrum has one or more i.p.s and yet the mapping is injective.

Comment: Urk, was not yet completely awake when I wrote that.

Comment: And in fact, $\sigma(x) = \{0\} \implies x = 0$ isn't a _necessary_ condition. Let $a = e$, then $\tilde{f}(a) = f(1)\cdot a$, so the map is not injective, whether we have the condition or not. But it's _sufficient_ for the non-injectivity in the presence of isolated points. For then, $f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} = g\lvert_{\sigma(a)}$ implies $\sigma(\tilde{f}(a) - \tilde{g}(a)) = \sigma((\tilde{f} - \tilde{g})(a)) = \sigma(\widetilde{(f-g)}(a)) = (f-g)(\sigma(a)) = \{0\}$, and thus $\tilde{f}(a) = \tilde{g}(a)$. If there are nonzero elements with spectrum $\{0\}$, this argument doesn't work, so in

Comment: that case, it could be that the map is injective even if the spectrum contains isolated points. But now I've thought about it enough to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine whether the map is injective, we first need to clarify the domain. If we let the domain be $\mathscr{O}(\sigma(a)) = \bigcup_{\sigma(a) \subset U} \mathscr{O}(U)$, where the $U$ are open sets, then the map $\Phi \colon f \mapsto \tilde{f}(a)$ is trivially not injective, we can let $U = D_1 \cup D_2$ consist of two disjoint open disks, with $\sigma(a) \subset D_1$, and let

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 0 &, z \in D_1 \\ 1 &, z \in D_2. \end{cases}$$

Then clearly $\tilde{f}(a) = 0$ but $f \neq 0$.

For an interesting question, we need to ignore the behaviour of $f$ "far away" from $\sigma(a)$. Thus we look at $\mathscr{O}(\sigma(a))/{\sim}$, where $f \sim g$ if and only if there is an open $W \supset \sigma(a)$ with $f\lvert_W = g\lvert_W$. Note that we can also describe $\mathscr{O}(\sigma(a))/{\sim}$ as the inductive limit of the Banach algebras $A(U) = \mathscr{C}(\overline{U}) \cap \mathscr{O}(U)$ where $U$ ranges over the bounded neighbourhoods of $\sigma(a)$.

Then $\Phi$ is always injective when $\sigma(a)$ contains no isolated points: By linearity of $\Phi$, we need to prove $\tilde{f}(a) = 0$ for an $f \in \mathscr{O}(U)$ implies $f \sim 0$, i.e. $f$ vanishes on a neighbourhood of $\sigma(a)$. The spectral mapping theorem gives us $\{0\} = \sigma(0) = \sigma(\tilde{f}(a)) = f(\sigma(a))$, so $f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} \equiv 0$ for $\tilde{f}(a) = 0$. Let $W$ be a connected component of $U$ intersecting $\sigma(a)$, and $w \in W\cap \sigma(a)$. Since $\sigma(a)$ contains no isolated points, it follows that $w$ is an accumulation point of $W \cap \sigma(a)$, and by the identity theorem, $f\lvert_W \equiv 0$. Thus if $V$ is the union of the components of $U$ intersecting $\sigma(a)$, we have $f\lvert_V \equiv 0$, and since clearly $\sigma(a) \subset V$, indeed $f \sim 0$.

If $\sigma(a)$ contains isolated points, then generally $\Phi$ is not injective, for $f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} \equiv 0$ does then not imply $f \sim 0$.

If the closed subalgebra of $A$ generated by $a$ satisfies $\sigma(x) = \{0\} \implies x = 0$, then $\Phi$ is never injective if $\sigma(a)$ has isolated points, for then $\tilde{f}(a) = 0 \iff f\lvert_{\sigma(a)} \equiv 0$, and if $p$ is an isolated point of $\sigma(a)$, we can take

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} (z - p) &, \lvert z-p\rvert < \delta \\ \quad 0 &, \lvert z-p\rvert > \delta,\end{cases}$$

where $0 < \delta < \operatorname{dist}(p,\sigma(a)\setminus \{p\})$ as an $f$ with $\tilde{f}(a) = 0$ but $f \nsim 0$.

Question: Can we have $f \mapsto \tilde{f}(a)$ injective even if $\sigma(a)$ has isolated points? Answer: Yes.

Let $A = \mathscr{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$, and consider

$$a \colon (x_0, x_1, x_2,\dotsc) \mapsto \bigl( 0, \tfrac{1}{1}x_0, \tfrac{1}{2} x_1, \tfrac{1}{3} x_2, \dotsc).$$

Then $\lVert a^k\rVert = \frac{1}{k!}$, so $\sigma(a) = \{0\}$. To see that $\Phi$ is injective for that $a$, consider a convergent power series

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n z^n.$$

Then we have

$$\tilde{f}(a) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n a^n,$$

since the series on the right converges absolutely in $\mathscr{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$. If $f \neq 0$, let $m = \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : c_n \neq 0\}$. Then

$$\langle \tilde{f}(a) e_0, e_m\rangle = \frac{c_m}{m!} \neq 0$$

and consequently $\tilde{f}(a) \neq 0$, showing that $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: Could you expand on why $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Since $\lVert a^k\rVert = 1/k!$, the spectral radius formula $\rho(a) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \lVert a^k\rVert^{1/k}$ gives $\rho(a) = 0$. You can also directly verify that $\lambda\operatorname{id} - a$ is invertible for all $\lambda\neq 0$, but IMO, the spectral radius is quicker here.

Comment: And $\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k!}}\to0$… why?

Comment: That follows for example from Stirling's formula. Less precise and more pedestrian is $k! > (k/3)^{k/2}$, which gives $\sqrt[k]{k!} > \sqrt{k/3}$.

Comment: Which last thing, for the record, can be proven by induction, seen as it holds if $k=1$ and assuming it for $k$ one merely has to note $k+1>\frac{(\frac{k+1}{3})^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{(\frac{k}{3})^{\frac k2}}=\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{3}}(1+\frac1k)^{\frac k2}$, which is easy since the $1+\frac1k$ factor is less than 1 and what is left is $\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{3}}$.

Comment: Or, for $k \geqslant 2$, we have $$k! \geqslant \prod_{m = \lfloor k/2\rfloor}^k m,$$ where each of the factors is $\geqslant \lfloor k/2\rfloor \geqslant k/3$, and there are at least $k - (\lfloor k/2\rfloor - 1) \geqslant k/2$ factors. Writing it down, I see that we could use $$\prod_{m = \lfloor k/2\rfloor + 1}^k m,$$ with each factor $> k/2$, and with $k - \lfloor k/2\rfloor = \lceil k/2\rceil \geqslant k/2$ factors, so we'd get the better bound $k! \geqslant (k/2)^{k/2}$. With a strict inequality for $k > 1$. Not that it matters.